# Configure IIS Express to use extension-less URLs in Classic pipeline mode using webforms

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

Is there anyway to configure IIS Express to support extension-less URLS?

Our production and development servers are running a website (webforms) app on IIS 6 and setup to process every request through isapi.dll. However, our local development machines are using IIS Express setup in Classic pipeline mode.

Currently if I am to request a resource from our dev or prod servers that doesn't have an extension, such as /about/ it processes fine, but if I were to request /about/ on our local development servers using IIS express I receive a 404.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check the site app pool in development server applicationhost.config file and make sure that .Net framework version is set to 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our website is running on .net 3.5, so I'm guessing this isn't an option.